# How to resolve pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: 1064 - save data on mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I'm trying to save the data scraped with scrapy to mysql. But, I have these issues:

1. No more support for `MySQLdb`. So, I have to use

   `import pymysql`

   `pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()` on `settings.py` file
2. On python 3 `%s` is deprecated and I have to use `.`format with the following **code:**

```
def close(self, reason):
        csv_file = max(glob.iglob('*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime)       
        mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                               user='demo',
                               passwd='123456',
                               db='testdb')
        cursor = mydb.cursor()

        csv_data = csv.reader(open(csv_file))

        row_count = 0
        for row in csv_data:
            if row_count != 0:
                cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO testtb(product, category) VALUES('{}','{}')".format(*row))
            row_count += 1

        mydb.commit()
        cursor.close()
```

> I have the following error

```
<bound method AutorSpider.close of <AutorSpider 'autor' at 0x7f64725d29b0>>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 151, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/home/pc/Escritorio/fpyautor/fpyautor/spiders/autor.py", line 109, in close
    cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO autortb(frase, categoria) VALUES({},'{}')'".format(*row))
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 516, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 727, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1066, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 683, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'titulo del item numero 1' at line 1")
```

is other simplier/eficcient way? because im saving the data at the end of the scraping task and if i got more results (3000 items )maybe this is a problem in future with bigger sites?

Comment: is `product` a varchar column ?

Comment: yes, thanks for comment

Comment: And your braces are not properly closed.

Comment: edited, edited.

Comment: Wait, are you still getting the error?

Comment: for large volume of data you could try  inserting in batches /  [multiple-row INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)

Comment: ok thanks for the idea, im running now the script again, i will comment in some minutes the result

Comment: yes, still the same error

Comment: Does your data have quotes(`'`)? If yes , Can you escape the string and try?

Comment: no, is text without format

Comment: Can you please attach some sample data please?

Comment: Product:
Se diferencia de los demás con información nueva
Category:
Tutorial

maybe the accent mark?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem I think. can you use try .. except and log the sql string which throws an exception please?

Comment: is on the first line:
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'titulo del item numero 1' at line 1") or can you tellme how to add these specific log that you mention? i never use a custom log error on scrapy

Comment: just assign the SQL to variable and on except method print the SQL , from which we can identify the data which causes the SQL to fail.

Comment: one field has the value Mick O'Brian   maybe the ' is the problem?, you ask that before and i think no one has the value ' but in 3000 rows at least 1 have these detail

Comment: conn.escape(row[0]) can help you. Wait i'll update my answer

Comment: ok, great thanks i wait the update

Comment: Can you check now please?

Comment: im running the scraper, in 10 minutes i publish the result, thanks !

Comment: Cool. I'll  wait :)

Comment: thank you very much, now is working and i learn some steps for debug errors in future, thanks a lot for the help and patience

Comment: anytime :) I'm glad I could be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[escape string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cext-escape-string.html) can help you

```
def close(self, reason):
    csv_file = max(glob.iglob('*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime)       
    mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                           user='demo',
                           passwd='123456',
                           db='testdb')
    cursor = mydb.cursor()

    csv_data = csv.reader(open(csv_file))

    row_count = 0
    for row in csv_data:
        if row_count != 0:
            product = mydb.escape_string(row[0])
            category = mydb.escape_string(row[1])
            #print category , product
            sql = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO testtb(product, category) VALUES ( "{}","{}")'.format(product,category)
            #print sql
            cursor.execute(sql)
            row_count += 1

    mydb.commit()
    cursor.close()
```